# Add different routes/screens to Flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to add multiple screens to my flutter app but can't get it to work. And there are no tutorials/ guides to do this.

Does anyone have an example on how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Navigator](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)

It's use is demonstrated in the Stocks example in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c8447c91a93cdee28eddb01ee3ace27b9362220f/packages/flutter/test/widgets/navigator_test.dart

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
...
onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
```

`Navigator` can also be used without `Scaffold`.

I run into an exception when I tried which I haven't yet found out how to fix. I plan to prepare a reproduction and file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You may also have a lot at https://github.com/goposse/fluro for a more advanced router.

Answer (score 0):

You have an article here http://sergiandreplace.com/2017/12/planets-flutter-routing-and-navigation/ (disclaimer, I'm the author)