# How To: Add flutter screen from one flutter app to another?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I See this:
[Add different routes/screens to Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091772/add-different-routes-screens-to-flutter-app)

but not the same thing.

So. I have several Flutter "TEMPLATE" apps, not real code, just the views not hooked up to the backend.
I am using Flutter Template A as the base with its screens.
Now I want to grab some Screens from Flutter Template B and Add/Import them into Flutter Template A
Again, I want to grab some Screens from Flutter Template C and Add/Import them into Flutter Template A

I am new to Flutter - but have over 35 development experiences in a broad range of languages.

Which files needed to move "A Screen" over and add to the router?

If anyone has done this, please help.

Answer (score 1):

It needs what it needs.  There are view, model, and controller classes, perhaps all in one file, or spread out across multiple directories.  So many ways of doing it that your question is unanswerable without looking at the code.  If you got these "templates" from a vendor, hopefully the vendor documented some of that.

Comment: And from looking at the directory structure I'm assuming any components that the screen may use as well. I've been looking at a lot of flutter applications and it looks like they all kind of have the same structure. So I thought maybe it was so easy that's why it wasn't documented ;)

Comment: No, they can put everything in `main.dart` or break things up by functional groups, or break things up by letters of the alphabet.  Fairly arbitrary.